Get One Drive Items Via Graph API In Paginated Way
I get the top 10 root children of my one drive through this API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$top=10
In response, I got a  "@odata.nextLink" to iterate through the next items.
"@odata.nextLink" looks like this:
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$top=10&$skiptoken=UGFnZWQ9VFJVRSZwX1NvcnRCZWhhdmlvcj0xJnBfRmlsZUxlYWZSZWY9VmljYWZlK0J1aWxkJnBfSUQ9MTM"
Suppose I got the 21-30th items in a response. Now I want to go back(get 11-20th items of my drive), how can I do that?
Since "Skip" parameter isn't supported how can I tell the API how many items to skip?
